# Blackberry Insert search icon in textfield?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

Scenario:
I want to add a search icon in the text field. And after I have written query and press enter then the search should work from the list view.

What I want:
I only want to place search icon in the textfield which I will press after my query. Like shown in the picture

[image]

I tried but its not placing it in the text field but outside it, so having difficult in it :S

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Override the `paint` method of `TextField`, draw the icon on desired position, and then call `super.paint(graphics)`.